# Is a string in PHP an array, or not?

Tags: php

I need to ask that what is string in PHP. Is it an array in PHP or not. Please give true justifications.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
so, it's not an array, although you can access char at given index just like it was an array.

Comment: True justifications? String type is not an array, although one _can_  access strings in array notation: `$str = "ABC"; echo $str[0] . $str[1] . $str[2] // outputs ABC like an array would.

Answer (score 4):

A [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in PHP is essentially a byte array (but not in the sense of a PHP's "array"); i.e., it's a buffer with only one piece of meta-data -- the size of the buffer.

An [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP is a double-linked hash table map, where the keys can be integers, strings, or a mixture of both.

In terms of PHP's type system, strings and arrays are two of the basic [types](http://php.net/types).

Answer (score 2):

You can read the documentation about php strings at

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, a string is a primitive type, meaning it's not an array.  See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) for the other primitive types supported by PHP.